# Google Spreadsheet API 500er errors

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The Google Drive API keeps throwing 500 errors at me and I have run out of ideas.

The returned pages for the 502 error reads:

```
That’s an error. The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. 
Please try again in 30 seconds.        
That’s all we know.
```

Sometimes I also get a 500 whose error message basically says "no idea" and does not even suggest retry.

I made a toy example to reproduce the problem:

```
import gspread
import random
import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

def main():

    json_key = json.load(open("/home/me/.credentials/API Project-56725514b81f.json"))
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    #prior to run, create a spreadsheet "Test" with the sheets "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3"
    filename =  "Test"
    spreadsheet = client.open(filename)
    while True:
        sheet='Sheet %i' %random.choice([1,2,3])
        wks = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheet)
        range= wks.range('A1:Z1')
        range[0].value = random.random()
        range[1].value = random.random()
        range[2].value = random.random()
        wks.update_cells(range)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I tested the following hypothesis:

- The allowed number of requests is exceeded -> I checked the [Developer Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) for my oauth user -> 10.000.000 requests per day are allowed, the user limit is also set high
- The error message indicated that waiting could help. I implemented exponential backoff as suggested in the [Api Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors/), but I get a "ResponseNotReady" exception from gspread no matter how long I wait until retry.

## More information

credentials object except "private_key" and "service_account_name":

{"id_token": null, "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "token_response": null, "client_id": null, "scope": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "token_expiry": null, "_class": "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials", "refresh_token": null, "_module": "oauth2client.client", "private_key_password": "notasecret", "access_token": null, "invalid": false, "assertion_type": null, "kwargs": {}, "client_secret": null, "revoke_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke", "store": null, "user_agent": null}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which library you're using, but the line 
`client = gspread.login(user@gmail.com, password)`
implies it's an out of date one. There is no longer any way to authenticate to Google APIs using username and password.

Depending on your programming language, you should either find a more up to date library, or program against the REST API directly.

Comment: I know:) This was only to provide an easily testable toy example. I use oauth to authenticate (see "what I tried")

Comment: I'm not sure how this is "easily testable" since it's guaranteed to not work. You might be better off pasting the code that you suspect should work. Also it would help to provide a link to the library that you're using, since as I said, it looks like it may be out of date.

Comment: ok. I thought it might be easier to analyze this way. I changed the example code tot the one I use, errors are the same. I use gspread https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Comment: Looking at the library, it is recently maintained and supports OAuth2, so ignore my supposition that it was out of date. Can you print the contents of your `credentials` object, and also an http trace.

Comment: I added the credentials content. For the trace call, I get status 405 "method not allowed"

Comment: reading the spec for gspread, it says 'OAuth2Credentials must be an object with a valid access_token attribute'. In your example, access token is null. You might want to try raising an issue against the developer as your problem seems specific to the library.

Comment: The access token is retrieved in the 'authorize' method. I use their recommended way from the docs to use oauth. https://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html  But to make sure I added it hardcoded to my credentials, it seems to make no difference.